# CSS content attr href won't validate

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a print CSS file for a university assignment. Part of my CSS is:

```
#footerRight a:after {   content: " (" attr(href) ") ";}
```

On the page it works fine. Definitely prints the href where it should. But the CSS won't validate. Errors I get are:

```
#footerRight a:after    Parse Error attr(href) ")";
#footerRight a:after    Parse Error }
```

I also tried a:: and a[href]: as a couple of blog posts I found suggested, but still it won't validate.

Any ideas? Sorry for the beginner level question.

Jackson

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
#footerRight a:after {
    content: attr(href) " ";
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to validate. I get the error: #footerRight a:after Value Error : content Parse Error attr(href) " "

Comment: Ah ok thanks for that. If that's the case I might as well just leave the CSS in the format from my OP, show my tutor that link and ask him to go easy on me when grading it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround the parenthesis with the single quotes:

```
#footerRight a:after {   content: " '(' attr(href) ') '";}
```

Had the same problem. It brought me here, but none of the answers solved my problem. This worked for me.

The outer `""` surround what will be the "content". The `''` are used to declare the text to show on the page.

by surrounding the parenthesis with `''` you are saying that these are literal strings that are concatenated to `attr(href)`.

note that the final single quote after ) in `') '` can be moved to the left one space if you want to exclude the space after the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes on the inside:

```
#footerRight a:after { content: " (' attr(href) ') ";}
```

Comment: This validates, but then (' attr(href) ') shows up instead of the URL of the link